# Can you be refused a visitor visa to US if you have bad Credit there?

Tags: visas, usa, payment-cards

I did my 3 years of College in the US, 2010-2013 due to finance issues I was unable to pay my credit card bill of a certain bank, which still lie unpaid. 
However I plan on visiting the US later this year; could I be denied visa for having an unpaid bill ?

Comment: Do you know if legal proceedings were started against you to recover the debt? If so, you might run into problems.

Answer (score 22):

As far as the law goes, you *can* be denied a visa for (almost) any or (almost) no reason, including if the consular officer doesn't like the color of your tie.

Whether you *will* be denied a visa for having unpaid credit card debt is therefore not an objective science, but *probably not*. The consular officer's task is to reject people who would attempt to immigrate illegally, overstay, or otherwise commit a crime if they were let into the US. Having unpaid debt is not a crime and is not immediately part of the consular officer's remit.

If the consular officer somehow gets into his head that having unpaid debt somehow makes you *more likely* to overstay or commit crimes, you could in principle be rejected on that basis, with few or no ways to challenge that decision. But it doesn't sound like something one would *expect* to happen.

Comment: +1, same for the UK. Unless the debt is with the NHS then they will refuse

Comment: The center of the question is more: do the CBP (US Border Police) and the credit history organisms/banks communicate together? In other words, without asking the visitor about it, may a border agent know about his debts?

Comment: @Vince Visas aren't issued at the border by CBP. They're issued in consulates by the State Department. It's a lot easier for a consular officer to gather a lot more information than would be convenient for a CBP officer to do routinely.

Comment: @cpast sorry you're right. So same question for these people, can an agent of the State Department request information about debts when granting a visa? If such rules are even known?

Comment: Wouldn't giving a visa somehow **increase** the odds of paying back the debt?