# US visa issuance with delinquent credit card debt?

Tags: visas, usa, payment-cards

I did 5 years of post-college education in the US, 1993 to 1997. Due to financial issues, I was unable to pay my credit card bill of a certain bank. The debt remains unpaid. I do plan to pay and solve the debt later this year. Could I be denied a visa for having an unpaid bill?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Can you be refused a visitor visa to US if you have bad Credit there?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48014)*. Also see *[Entry into US with unpaid medical bills and ticket for careless driving](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6543)* The short answer is that it is possible, but unlikely. An immigration officer wants to make sure you do not overstay; they are not collections agents for the banks.